# Bind to already rendered HTML

Tags: angular

We want to develop the live-site management application using Angular2 where users will be able to change the website appearance. This application would work with our REST API on top of the site.

Website's HTML is rendered by PHP engine. Inside that HTML we have some elements with class attribute `class="my-container-2"`.

In Angular2 app we want to detect those elements and based on them, make a proper API calls.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem. Once we added the Angular2 component and placed it into already rendered HTML, it removed all HTML tags inside:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<live-management>
    <div class="my-container-2"></div> <-- this tag is removed by Angular2
</live-management>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Looks like there is only a way to provide a HTML template/template URL directly in Angular2 components. I can understand it's for the security reasons and I respect it, although it doesn't work for our use case.

We were thinking to downgrade to Angular 1, as this what I described can be easily done with the older version of Angular. But on the other hand we wanted to go with the modern framework.

Any thoughts and recommendations on this? Maybe there is some kind of solution to that already?

Comment: "detect those elements and based on them, make a proper API calls" - what sort of conditions are required to make proper API calls?

Comment: based on ``my-container-2`` class where 2 is an id, we want to call the API endpoint ``/api/containers/:id`` which for instance will return container's settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two parts to this: rendering the php generated html, and querying the html class names.

The first can be solved using `<ng-content>` or `<template>`... [Transclusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content);

```
@Component({
    selector: 'live-management',
    templateUrl: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class LiveManagement {}
```

As for the second part I am a little less certain, but would recommend looking into the [`@ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html) approach;

*Untested Code Ahead:*

```
@Directive({selector: '[.my-container]'})
export class IdSelector{
    @Input() id: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'live-management',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class LiveManagement implements AfterViewInit{
    @ContentChildren(IdSelector) elements: QueryList<any>;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('My element id: ' + this.elements.id;);
    }
}
```

Assuming the above code works (probably with a bit of finessing), you would have to adjust your PHP to add the number to the id attribute as apposed to appended to the class name.

In summery I do think it is possible to achieve this in Angular 2, however as new as it is you may have a hard time at points. With this said I strongly recommend not using Angular 1, for a lot of [reasons](https://medium.com/@mnemon1ck/why-you-should-not-use-angularjs-1df5ddf6fc99#.7j3uxuusf). If Angular 2 isn't going to work for your use-case look into [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)